# Creating formatted references with different citation styles to academic papers without DOIs

Tags: r, bibtex, citations

I'd like to format references to academic papers in different citation styles with R.

With package rcrossref, I can easily create citations to certain articles based on their DOIs in the style you specify. However, not all papers have a DOI, so I'm looking for an easy way to get citations in text with different styles based on the article info from a BibTeX entry or some other type of input.

Using rcrossref:
The package contains `length(rcrossref::get_styles())` 2209 different styles.

For example, you can get citations in text to some highly cited papers (DOIs from this source: https://doi.org/10.1038/514550a) with different styles in text in a list element as follows:

```
library(rcrossref)
# some DOIs of interest
dois <- c("10.1038/514550a", "10.1038/227680a0", "10.1016/0003-2697(76)90527-3",  "10.1073/Pnas.74.12.5463", "10.1016/0003-2697(87)90021-2", "10.1107/S0108767307043930")


# APA cv style
cr_cn(dois = dois, format = "text", style="apa-cv")
# same with Chicago style
cr_cn(dois = dois, format = "text", style="chicago-note-bibliography")
# same with Vancouver style
cr_cn(dois = dois, format = "text", style="vancouver")
```

Now, say I have an entry without a DOI f.ex. in BibTex format, like:

```
@article {PMID:14907713,    Title = {Protein measurement with the Folin phenol reagent},    Author = {LOWRY, OH and ROSEBROUGH, NJ and FARR, AL and RANDALL, RJ},   Number = {1},   Volume = {193},     Month = {November},     Year = {1951},  Journal = {The Journal of biological chemistry},    ISSN = {0021-9258},     Pages = {265—275},  URL = {http://www.jbc.org/content/193/1/265.long} }
```

and I'd like to format also this entry f.ex in APA cv, Chicago and Vancouver styles, and get the result in text, how can I do that? I Haven't found a function for that. Is there any way currently available for this task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it doesn't look like `rcrossref` supports this because everything happens on their API server and there doesn't appear to be a way to specify a raw bibtex entry that doesn't have a DOI.

However, it does appear that `pandoc` which is usually installed with `RStudio` and is used by `rmarkdown` has support for citation formatting. I tried to do a bit of reverse engineering to see if it would be possible to just produce the citation for a given entry. Here's the function I've created.

```
citation <- function(bib, csl="chicago-author-date.csl", toformat="plain", cslrepo="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/citation-style-language/styles/master") {
  if (!file.exists(bib)) {
    message("Assuming input is literal bibtex entry")
    tmpbib <- tempfile(fileext = ".bib")
    on.exit(unlink(tmpbib), add=TRUE)
    if(!validUTF8(bib)) {
      bib <- iconv(bib, to="UTF-8")
    }
    writeLines(bib, tmpbib)
    bib <- tmpbib
  }
  if (tools::file_ext(csl)!="csl") {
    warning("CSL file name should end in '.csl'")
  }
  if (!file.exists(csl)) {
    cslurl <- file.path(cslrepo, csl)
    message(paste("Downling CSL from", cslurl))
    cslresp <- httr::GET(cslurl, httr::write_disk(csl))
    if(httr::http_error(cslresp)) {
      stop(paste("Could not download CSL.", "Code:", httr::status_code(cslresp)))
    }
  }
  tmpcit <- tempfile(fileext = ".md")
  on.exit(unlink(tmpcit), add=TRUE)
  
  writeLines(c("---","nocite: '@*'","---"), tmpcit)
  rmarkdown::find_pandoc()
  command <- paste(shQuote(rmarkdown:::pandoc()), 
                   "--filter", "pandoc-citeproc",
                   "--to", shQuote(toformat),
                   "--csl", shQuote(csl),
                   "--bibliography", shQuote(bib), 
                  shQuote(tmpcit))
  rmarkdown:::with_pandoc_safe_environment({
    result <- system(command, intern = TRUE)
    Encoding(result) <- "UTF-8"
  })
  result
}
```

You can pass in your reference, and it will convert it using a standard "CSL" file. These CSL files are what control the formatting. There is a giant repo with different CSL for different formats [here](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles). You can specify a CSL file and if the file doesn't exist, this function will automatically download it from the repo.

You can either pass in a "raw" citation

```
test <- "@article {PMID:14907713,    Title = {Protein measurement with the Folin phenol reagent},    Author = {LOWRY, OH and ROSEBROUGH, NJ and FARR, AL and RANDALL, RJ},   Number = {1},   Volume = {193},     Month = {November},     Year = {1951},  Journal = {The Journal of biological chemistry},    ISSN = {0021-9258},     Pages = {265-275},  URL = {http://www.jbc.org/content/193/1/265.long} } "
citation(test)
```

Or if the data was in a file, you could use the file name

```
writeLines(test, "test.bib") 
citation("test.bib")
```

And if you wanted to use a different CSL, you can just set the name of the CSL file in the `CSL=` parameter

```
citation("test.bib", csl="apa-cv.csl")
citation("test.bib", csl="chicago-note-bibliography.csl")
citation("test.bib", csl="vancouver.csl")
```

Comment: Brilliant - but it appears the 
                   "--filter", "pandoc-citeproc",
line now needs to be
                   "--citeproc",